# What is the datatype returned by the bitwise complement operator?

Tags: c

I try to understand what exactly the bitwise complement operator in C returns. (Not in terms of 'which value', but in terms of 'which datatype'. I guess I understand how the bit-complement theorethically works, so no need to reexplain that)

Consider the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   char c = 'A';
   printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(c), sizeof(~c));
   return 0; 
}
```

While the first sizeof() returns 1, the latter returns 4 on my machine.

So my question is: Of which datatype is ~c?

I'm working on a 32Bit Linux, would the result change to 8 if I'd work on a 64Bit machine? My best guess so far is, that the bitwise operation is applied to a register and the return value is not casted back to a char value.. And can this behaviour be different for other compilers, or does the C standard define what is returned by ~c?

Comment: `~` is 1's complement, not 2's complement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is going on with bitwise operators and integer promotion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473958/what-is-going-on-with-bitwise-operators-and-integer-promotion)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Operator `~`, before the actual operation, performs integer promotions<sup>1</sup> on the type,
so the type of `~c` is implementation defined, either<sup>2</sup> `int` or `unsigned int`.

Also note that the result of `sizeof` is the type `size_t` which should be printed with `%zu` not `%d`.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from ISO:IEC 9899:201x 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers 2)
If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a
bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned
int. These are called the integer promotions. 58) All other types are unchanged by the
integer promotions. 58) The integer promotions are applied only: as part of the usual arithmetic conversions, to certain
argument expressions, to the operands of the unary +, -, and ~ operators, and to both operands of the
shift operators, as specified by their respective subclauses.

<sup>2</sup> To clarify why both types and not only `int`. This is because `char` may be either signed or unsigned, and it is permitted by the C Standard for `unsigned char` to not be represented by an `int`, because the range of the latter could be too small. Had you chosen the type `signed char`, it could only be promoted to `int`.

Answer (score 7):

From 6.5.3.3, Unary arithmetic operators:

*Constraints*:

> The operand of the unary `+` or `-` operator shall have arithmetic type; **of the `~` operator, integer type;** of the `!` operator, scalar type.

*Semantics*:

> The result of the `~` operator is the bitwise complement of its (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set.) The integer promotions are performed on the operand, and **the result has the promoted type**.

To summarize: The operand of `~` has an integral type, the operand value is promoted according to the integer promotions, and the type of the result of the expression is that promoted type. (Integer promotions turn anything "smaller" than an `int` into either an `int` or an `unsigned int`, and leave everything else as is.)