# Why does bit operation on integer types smaller than 4 bytes behave unexpectedly?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Please consider the code example where I want to check if all bits in a unsigned integer variable are set. `IntegerType` is replaced by uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t uint64_t.

The question: Why does the assertion succeed for IntegerType = uint32_t and uint64_t while it fails for uint16_t and uint8_t?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>

IntegerType bitset = -1; // set all bits to true

IntegerType t = ~bitset;
bool bAllBitsSet1 = (t == 0);
bool bAllBitsSet2 = ((~bitset) == 0);

assert(bAllBitsSet1 == bAllBitsSet2);
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473958/what-is-going-on-with-bitwise-operators-and-integer-promotion

Comment: At least GCC emits a `warning: promoted ~unsigned is always non-zero [-Wsign-compare]`.

Comment: The constant value minus 1 is always of type int. Your assignment does an implicit cast which might not do what you expect

Comment: @JVApen How so?

Comment: It doesn't require to set all bits to true

Comment: @JVApen Why not? I thought it did.

Comment: Assigning -1 to unsigned integer types is a common way to produce the largest unsigned value. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/

Comment: I stand corrected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens due to integer promotion: the first expression casts `~bitset` back into the shorter type, while the second expression uses full integer value.

For integer types shorter than `int` the value gets promoted to `int` before performing an operation, in this case, before applying `~` to it.

Consider `uint16_t` for an example. When you write

```
uint16_t t = ~bitset;
```

the value of `bitset` gets promoted to `int`, so it becomes `0x0000FFFF` on a 32-bit platform. Then `~` is applied, producing `0xFFFF0000`. Finally, the result gets written back into `t`, chopping off high bits. Therefore, `t` is zero.

On the other hand, when you compare `~bitset` to zero directly, the comparison fails, because `0xFFFF0000` is not zero.

Comment: Does promotion preserve the signed/unsigned property? Also, why does promotion take place anyway?

Comment: @Fabian Promotion does not preserve the sign. If `int` can represent all values of a type, the expression gets converted to `int`. My best guess as to why this is done this way is that it's done to save CPU cycles: CPUs often operate on `int`s because they lack corresponding instructions for shorter types, so if the standard required casting back to short int, this would force compilers emit instructions that are seldom needed. Since you are given an option to keep the `int` or to cast it back, standard writers decided against requiring universal truncation.

Comment: " why does promotion take place anyway?" 
 because that the way this language works https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion