# Unexpected behaviour on underflow of unsigned char

Tags: c++, integer-arithmetic, unsigned-char

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    unsigned char result1 {0};
    unsigned char result2 {0};

    result1 = (result1 - 1) % 8;

    result2 = result2 - 1;
    result2 = result2 % 8;

    std::cout << "result1 is " << std::to_string (result1) << '\n';
    std::cout << "result2 is " << std::to_string (result2) << '\n';
}
```

results in the following output:

```
result1 is 255
result2 is 7
```

Why is it that the calculation of result1 and result2 has different results?

I tried several compilers but they all produce the same result so it must be something I don't understand.

Comment: Note that while `result2` is an `unsigned char`, `result2 - 1` is an `int`: `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(result2 - 1), int>);`

Comment: You are observing [integer promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279197/why-does-bit-operation-on-integer-types-smaller-than-4-bytes-behave-unexpectedly)

Comment: [There is no such thing as "integer underflow"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Arithmetic in C++ is never done in a type with rank lower than `int`.

If you apply `-` or `%` to an `unsigned char` value, which has rank lower than `int`, it will first undergo *integer promotion*, meaning it will be converted to an `int` with the same value (assuming `int` can hold all values of `unsigned char`, which is practically always the case).

The literals `1` and `8` are also of type `int`, so that then the operations will be performed in the common type `int`, also with an `int` result. Notably, this means all arithmetic in your example happens with *signed* values.

Only when you assign back to the `unsigned char` variable is the signed `int` value converted back to an unsigned `unsigned char` value.

So both `result1 - 1` and `result2 - 1` are `int`s with value `-1`.

The way `%` treats negative values in C++, `(result1 - 1) % 8` is then also an `int` with value `-1`.

Conversion of `-1` to `unsigned char` results in `255` if the width of `(unsigned) char` is `8` because such conversion is specified to keep the value congruent 2^n where n is the width of the target type.

However, conversion of `result2 - 1` to `unsigned char` to store in `results2` also results in `255`, so in `result2 % 8` the operation is `255 % 8` (in `int`) which gives in the `int` result `7`, which converted back to `unsigned char` is still `7`.

---

Technically it is also allowed for `unsigned char` to have the same width as `int` (although in that case both need to have at least `16` bit width, because that is the minimum width required for `int` by the standard.)

In that case, `int` can't hold all values of `unsigned char` and integer promotion would promote to `unsigned int` instead. Then, the *usual arithmetic conversions* will prefer `unsigned int` over the `int` type of the literal operands and so all arithmetic will be done in `unsigned int`.

Under these circumstances both of your outputs will give `7`. Whether any C++ implementation with these properties actually exists, I don't know, but it is permitted by the standard.